# Observe LiveData to indicate whether or not to display TextViews in MVVM

Tags: performance, android, kotlin, mvvm

In the context of MVVM, is this an efficient way to communicate to the view that I should display some TextViews? Any advice on how I can improve it?

ViewModel code:

```
private var _shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent
```

Activity code:

```
viewModel.shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent.observe(this, Observer { shouldDisplay ->
            if (!shouldDisplay) {
                binding.textviewDischargeCurrentTitle.visibility = GONE
                binding.textviewDischargeCurrent.visibility = GONE
                binding.textviewDischargeTimeTitle.visibility = GONE
                binding.textviewDischargeTime.visibility = GONE
            }
        })
```

Comment: Do you also want to show the view? currently, your code will only hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will asume you are using ConstraintLayout and also want to show the views (currently your code only hides the views) so I think it can be improved in 2 ways.

The first way is to use `View.isVisible` extension from [google's lib](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list#androidxcoreview) instead of setting GONE. So you code will become like this:

```kotlin
viewModel.shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent.observe(this, Observer { shouldDisplay ->
    binding.textviewDischargeCurrentTitle.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
    binding.textviewDischargeCurrent.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
    binding.textviewDischargeTimeTitle.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
    binding.textviewDischargeTime.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
})
```

and the second way is to use Constraint Group. Add a new element in XML with all the view's ids you want to hide:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
    android:id="@+id/textview_group"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textviewDischargeCurrent, textviewDischargeCurrentTitle,textviewDischargeTime,textviewDischargeTimeTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and then in your code:

```kotlin
viewModel.shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent.observe(this, Observer { shouldDisplay ->
// those are no longer needed
//    binding.textviewDischargeCurrentTitle.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
//    binding.textviewDischargeCurrent.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
//    binding.textviewDischargeTimeTitle.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
//    binding.textviewDischargeTime.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
    binding.textviewGroup.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
})
```

Also `Observer {` can be removed so the final result with Constraint Group will be:

```kotlin
viewModel.shouldDisplayDischargeCurrent.observe(this) { shouldDisplay ->
    binding.textviewGroup.isVisible = !shouldDisplay
}
```

Regarding performance I could not find much about this. Maybe someone else can comment about it. Personaly I would go with Constraint Group and `View.isVisible`